# Javascript url.location & replaced with?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a language selection radio button in my html page and on selection of a language I make the call to the same url appending '?lang='. This I am doing via js and when the url is submitted the & is replaced with ?. Below is my js code.

```
function removeBookmarkFromUrl(url) {
    var arr = url.split("#");
    return arr[0];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name=lang]').change(function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var selectedLang = $(this).attr('id');
        url = removeBookmarkFromUrl(url);       
        if (url.indexOf('?lang') >= 0 || url.indexOf('&lang') >= 0) {
            var pos = (url.indexOf('?lang') >=0 ) ? url.indexOf('?lang') : url.indexOf('&lang');
            var currentLang = url.slice(pos + 6, pos + 8);
            if (url.charAt(pos) == '?') {
                url = url.replace('?lang=' + currentLang, '?lang=' + selectedLang);
                window.location = url;
            } else if (url.charAt(pos) == '&') {
                url = url.replace('&lang=' + currentLang, '&lang=' + selectedLang);
                window.location = url;
            }
        } else {
            if (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
                window.location = url + '&lang=' + selectedLang;
            } else {
                window.location = url + '?lang=' + selectedLang;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now when I make the language selection the url in the browser is http://localhost:8080/test/report.htm?count=40&name=jerry?lang=en. I debugged the code and saw url to be http://localhost:8080/test/report.htm?count=40&name=jerry&lang=en but this is getting changed on submission.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be fine. You should consider to use functions, they make debugging a lot easier.

```js
function removeBookmarkFromUrl(url) {
    var arr = url.split("#");
    return arr[0];
}

function getLangUrl(url, lang){
  url = removeBookmarkFromUrl(url);
  if (url.indexOf('?lang') >= 0 || url.indexOf('&lang') >= 0) {
      var pos = (url.indexOf('?lang') >=0 ) ? url.indexOf('?lang') : url.indexOf('&lang');
      var currentLang = url.slice(pos + 6, pos + 8);
      if (url.charAt(pos) == '?') {
        url = url.replace('?lang=' + currentLang, '?lang=' + lang);
        return url;
      }
      else if (url.charAt(pos) == '&') {
         url = url.replace('&lang=' + currentLang, '&lang=' + lang);
         return url;
      }
  } else {
      if (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
        return url + '&lang=' + lang;
      } else {
         return url + '?lang=' + lang;
      }
   }
}

var url;
url = "http://localhost:8080/test/report.htm";
console.log(url, " \n-> ", getLangUrl(url, 'de'));

url = "http://localhost:8080/test/report.htm?lang=en";
console.log(url, " \n-> ", getLangUrl(url, 'de'));

url = "http://localhost:8080/test/report.htm?count=40&name=jerry";
console.log(url, " \n-> ", getLangUrl(url, 'de'));

url = "http://localhost:8080/test/report.htm?count=40&name=jerry&lang=en";
console.log(url, " \n-> ", getLangUrl(url, 'de'));
```